# ArangoDB: filter out document attributes in a collection query

Tags: attributes, arangodb, aql

I've got an ArangoDB collection containing a lot of different types of documents (that is with different sets of attributes).

I would like to make a select query and filter out some attributes, that is return all but a couple of predefined attributes of the selected documents.

For example, if this the selected subset:

```
{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, h:8}
{a:21, b:22, c:23, d:4, w:5, p:81}
{a:31, b:22, c:63, f:4, e:5, u:82}
{a:41, b:32, c:53, g:4, h:5, l:83}
{a:51, b:42, c:53, h:4, j:5, n:84}
{a:61, b:52, c:33, i:4, u:5, m:85}
```

I'd like to return all attributes but 'b', 'c', 'd':

```
{a:1,  e:5, h:8},
{a:21,  w:5, p:81}
{a:31,  f:4, e:5, u:82}
{a:41,  g:4, h:5, l:83}
{a:51,  h:4, j:5, n:84}
{a:61,  i:4, u:5, m:85}
```

What is the most efficient way to do this  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `UNSET` AQL function to do this.
The following AQL query returns all documents from the collection, but for each document unsets the mentioned attributes `b`, `c`, and `d`.

```
FOR doc IN collection 
  RETURN UNSET(doc, ['b', 'c', 'd' ])
```

The result of the query for the above data set would be (note that I also excluded the attributes `_id`, `_key` and `_rev` here for brevity):

```
[ 
  { 
    "a" : 41, 
    "h" : 5, 
    "g" : 4, 
    "l" : 83 
  }, 
  { 
    "a" : 31, 
    "e" : 5, 
    "f" : 4, 
    "u" : 82 
  }, 
  { 
    "a" : 61, 
    "u" : 5, 
    "i" : 4, 
    "m" : 85 
  }, 
  { 
    "a" : 1, 
    "e" : 5, 
    "h" : 8 
  }, 
  { 
    "a" : 51, 
    "h" : 4, 
    "j" : 5, 
    "n" : 84 
  }, 
  { 
    "a" : 21, 
    "w" : 5, 
    "p" : 81 
  } 
]
```